# Cálculo de Diferença entre Datas

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte DF:

```
MATRICULA <- c('111','222','333','444','555')
DATA_INICIO <- c('10/12/2017','31/12/2014', 
'30/06/2015','20/11/2016','01/04/2014')
DATA_FIM <- c('10/12/2017', '01/01/2015', '02/07/2016', '03/12/2016', 
'13/04/2014')

DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM).
```

Como faço para incluir uma coluna de diferença de datas (em dias) entre as duas datas (`DATA_FIM` (-) `DATA_INICIO`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O R base tem funções para fazer cálculos com datas, para casos simples tais como a diferença em dias [(ou outras unidades)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html) não é necessário carregar pacotes externos.

```
DADOS$DIFERENÇA <- with(DADOS, as.Date(DATA_FIM, "%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(DATA_INICIO, "%d/%m/%Y"))
DADOS
#  MATRICULA DATA_INICIO   DATA_FIM DIFERENÇA
#1       111  10/12/2017 10/12/2017    0 days
#2       222  31/12/2014 01/01/2015    1 days
#3       333  30/06/2015 02/07/2016  368 days
#4       444  20/11/2016 03/12/2016   13 days
#5       555  01/04/2014 13/04/2014   12 days
```

Se não quiser este tipo de saída, com `days` na coluna, basta fazer

```
DADOS$DIFERENÇA <- as.integer(DADOS$DIFERENÇA)
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
library(lubridate)
DADOS %>% 
   mutate(diferenca = as.numeric(dmy(DATA_FIM) - dmy(DATA_INICIO)))

  MATRICULA DATA_INICIO   DATA_FIM diferenca
1       111  10/12/2017 10/12/2017         0
2       222  31/12/2014 01/01/2015         1
3       333  30/06/2015 02/07/2016       368
4       444  20/11/2016 03/12/2016        13
5       555  01/04/2014 13/04/2014        12
```

Note que uso a função `dmy` do `lubridate` que converte strings em data de acordo com a ordem em que estão dia (`d`) , mês (`m`) e ano (`y`). Se sua data estivesse no formato aaaa/mm/dd você poderia usar a função `ymd` por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

O R possui uma função chamada difftime, que calcula essa diferença em anos, dias, meses entre outros.

Primeiro você precisará transformar os seus dados em data, para depois usar essa função.

```
DADOS$DATA_INICIO = as.Date(DADOS$DATA_INICIO, '%d/%m/%Y')
DADOS$DATA_FIM = as.Date(DADOS$DATA_INICIO, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Depois você pode calcular de acordo com a sua necessidade e colocar no mesmo data.frame:

```
DADOS$INTERVALO = difftime(DADOS$DATA_FIM, DADOS$DATA_INICIO, units = 'days')
```